# Using bundle with rvm at hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I am try

```
hosting_barthez@lithium:~/projects/taxes/current$ bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1276:in `gem'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle:18
```

but when I write

```
hosting_barthez@lithium:~/projects/taxes/current$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.15
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is obvious. You got error because you were trying to use `bundle` command which comes with `bundler` gem only, without installing it. You have to install `bundler` to use `bundle`.